# Angular: default config for component

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

how can I apply this config to my component. Im using a controller with a config setting by me, but how can  I provide a default config set of options like in a jquery plugin:

```
    $.fn.helloWorld = function( options ) {

        // Establish our default settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            descriptionTemplate.content: 'Hello, World!',
            type         : 'tab',
            id           : null
        }, options);

    }
```

my controller is providing this object:

```
vm.tabs = [
    {
        id: '1',
        type: 'tab',
        sections: {
            tabTitle: 'The Caribbean'
        },
        descriptionTemplate : {
            content: 'text goes here'
        },
        active: true
    }
];
```

Comment: You should create a corresponding provider and configure it. From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe): "You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular.config in your case that would be use for configuration purpose

**Constant**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
.config('constants', {
   id: 1,
   tab: 'test',
   description: 'test'
});
```

Now you created a config which will available everywhere, you can also extend this anywhere using `angular.extend({}, object1, object2)`

**Controller**

```
app .controller('Ctrl',fuction($scope, constants){
   //you can further extend constants using extend method
   angular.extend(constants,{
       id: 2,
       tab: 'test1',
       description: 'test1'
   });
});
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @pankajparkar. A very clean explanation.